# Trying to make a piece of my arduino code time-based

Tags: arduino

I currently have an arduino with a wifi shield, hooked up to a PIR-detector and a website. This is supposed to control a lock. I have gotten all of this to work, but there is one part I'd like to improve on. Would it be possible for me to change the PIR detector, so that if there has been movement in the past, say, 5 seconds, it will allow it to open (if the letter is also correct)? The way it does it now, it has to constantly have movement, otherwise it'll lock in seconds. Please note that i'm new to arduino coding, so go easy on me

```
  while (client.available()){
int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1); //Input from PIR-detector
Serial.println(sensorValue2);
char c = client.read();
Serial.write(c);
if ((sensorValue2 > 0.0) && (c == 'L')) { //If the input from the detector is over 0.0, and the text which is received from the website is 'L', the lock will open
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
}
else{
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
}
```

}

Comment: look at the "blink without delay" example, you need something just like it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `millis()` function to use a timer withou pausing your arduino. [This Tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) should help you do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use `millis()`

Let's say that `previousMilis` is the time at which the movement was first triggered or whatever you want.

```
if ( triggered(0 ) {
  previousMillis() = millis();
}

while (millis() - previousMillis < 5000) {
  // do something while the 5 seconds is being counted down
  // this will update each milliseconds
}
```